# How to disable flashing VirtuaWin systray icon? Window is not responding

Tags: windows, window-manager, virtual-desktop, virtual-desktop-manager, virtuawin

I have to run an application which is not responding so ViruaWin isn't able to manage it. (There is a "1 window not responding" tooltip on its systray icon.) Because of the hanging VirtuaWin flashes its systray icon which is really disturbing. I'd like to disable the flashing.

I've read the [Window not responding?](http://sourceforge.net/projects/virtuawin/forums/forum/257054/topic/2179548) forum topic and I've also tried to create a new Window Rule with the class name of the hanging application but it doesn't work, the icon is still flashing.

The hanging application from the WinList module:

[image: Hanging application in the list of WinList module]

The created Window Rule:

[image: Created Window Rule]

How can I disable the flashing (without hiding the systray icon)?

Comment: On Windows 10 there is a "Windows.Ui.Core.CoreWindow" that is not responding. I'm guessing that if there would be a way to un-manage a window by name then it would be a good workaround.

Answer (score 4):

So this how you deal with it...

First you need to **find problematic windows**:

1. Open VW setup.
2. Go to Modules -> WinList -> use Configure button.
3. Right click on WinList window title bar and choose Stop Managing item.
4. Switch between desktops until you get a blinking tray icon.
5. Refresh the list and sort by S column. You should have some windows with "H" in S coulmn (like on the image below).
6. Take note of the Class of the hanging window(s).

[image: Vista Example of a position of problematic windows list.]

Now you need to **change window rules**:

1. From tray icon menu choose Window Rules item.
2. Type in Class name (or Window name) and choose Never manage windows of this type option.
3. Click Add button to add the rule. And OK to save rules.
4. This is important - the rule will NOT be active until you restart VW. The quickest way is to Exit VirtuaWin and run it again. Reapply Rules might work too.

For *Windows 10* I added `tooltips_class32` and `Windows.UI.Core.*`. You might also want to add similar rule for `ApplicationFrameWindow` class to get rid of windows with empty title in application lists.

[image: Configuration of rules. Windows 10 example.]

For *Vista* I'm guessing that would be `TscShellContainerClass`.

Comment: It still blinks in Windows 10

Comment: Maybe the rules need to be on top. See updated image. This is from Windows 10 Pro, so YMMV.

Comment: The help file says that the order of the rules is not important

Comment: After doing this it was still blinking for me in Windows 10. But closing then restarting VirtuaWin seems to have fixed it. Hasn't blinked since.

Answer (score 1):

[It should be fixed in v4.5.](https://sourceforge.net/p/virtuawin/bugs/236/#a4d2) However, personally I would hide the icon and use the KvasdoPager module instead. The taskbar is still neat, but I still can **manage the apps I don't need now**.

[image]